# Listen to a button click in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The html of a facebook like button is the following:

```
<div aria-label="J’aime" class="oajrlxb2 bp9cbjyn g5ia77u1 mtkw9kbi tlpljxtp qensuy8j ppp5ayq2 
goun2846 ccm00jje s44p3ltw mk2mc5f4 rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 j83agx80 
mg4g778l btwxx1t3 pfnyh3mw p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x tgvbjcpo hpfvmrgz jb3vyjys 
rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso l9j0dhe7 i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of du4w35lb lzcic4wl abiwlrkh p8dawk7l 
buofh1pr taijpn5t" role="button" tabindex="0">
```

I put the following in content.js , a content_script :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2").addEventListener("click",
  function(){ alert("Hello World!"); }
);
```

I would expect this to alert me with "Hello World" when clicking a like button, but it is not. How comes?

I also get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
```

But I have seen it being used in other solutions?

EDIT:
I changed content.js to this:

```
var likeButtonList = document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2");

for (i = 0; i < likeButtonList.length; i++) {
  likeButtonList[i].addEventListener("click",
    function(){ alert("Hello World!"); }
  );
}
```

I am trying to listen to every button at once but this is still not working?

EDIT2:
The page was not loaded properly. It was fixed by doing the following in content.js:

```
var likeButtonList;

function getLikeButtons(){
  likeButtonList = document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2");

  for (i = 0; i < likeButtonList.length; i++) {
    likeButtonList[i].addEventListener("click",
      function(){ alert("Hello World!"); }
    );
  }
}

setInterval(getLikeButtons, 1111);
```

Comment: are u able to get this working

Comment: not yet able to see the alert, I added new code in my edit, perhaps the page is not fully loaded when the code is run?

Comment: did u apply the below code and if you did. does it show any error

Comment: yes there is still error codes

Comment: i got it to work thank you

Comment: can i get a glimpse of the error

Comment: oh okk..u welcome

Comment: I still get error messages even though it is working... strange

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

and

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: also always use let instead of var..jst a good code tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2")
```

this returns a collection and not an element you can attach an event to(because many elements can have the same class).You will have to access the element within the collection using an index. For example access the first element in the collection

```
document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2")[0].addEventListener("click",
  function(){ alert("Hello World!"); }
);
```